# Generate dynamic email-id in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

We have API for users to register in website. From our side, we have automated API for register and using groovy as well for some assertion.

What we are doing daily, changing user email parameter value first and then run API to check if it register new user or not. If we don't change email then it returns

> "Email already exist".

So is there any method or way which can be achieved from soap ui or groovy to change email parameter value each time before we run API to test.

As we want to check register API daily, we are looking for solution of changing email address daily from manual to something automate.

Comment: if it's only for testing purpose why don't you try generating random string as email username?

Comment: @YohanesGultom - using soapui or groovy?

Comment: using groovy sounds easier. I haven't got much experience with soapui

Comment: @YohanesGultom- Yes but for example if I generate random string from groovy then how can I pass that string as value of parameter email in soap ui request?

Comment: are you using soap or rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below should be helpful, no extra groovy script is required, use inline script as mentioned:

In the **xml**

```
<email>${= java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}@test.com</email>
```

In the **json**

```
{
  "email" : "${= java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}@test.com"
}
```

If you want short value than random uuid, you may use:
**change from** : `${= java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}`
**to** : `${= System.currentTimeMillis()}`

Comment: Awesome solution. It works exactly how I was looking for.